# Web scraping Fidelity.com using Python and Selenium can't click button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have begun to create a script in Python using Selenium to web scrape my account at Fidelity.com
I am able to login and click some buttons on the webpage, but am having a problem with the following button code.

Download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='posweb-share-button']")
Download.click()

Here is the html:

```html
<button id="posweb-share-button" class="posweb-share-button pvd-btn btn-anchor posweb-metrics" type="button" aria-label="Download and Print Positions data" data-metrics="shareIcon" aria-describedby="posweb-share-popover"><pvd-icon icon="share" label="Download and Print" aria-hidden="true"></pvd-icon></button>
```

The code to login works find, I am to click other buttons on the webpage using code, but nothing happens with the above code, and I get "Process finished with exit code 0".

Comment: Why did you put "Download" after locator, and before click?

Comment: Download is just a variable I used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing this as a variable you need to separate the code like this:

```
Download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='posweb-share-button']")
Download.click()
```

Comment: It is on 2 lines in Python. When I pasted it in the original message, it did not format properly. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Is that button on the homepage of Fidelity? Or somewhere else?  Your code looks fine to me, but hard to tell for sure without knowing location of button

Comment: Here is the Python script starting after I login to Fidelity.
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Account positions").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
Dividend = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='posweb-dividend-view-button']")
Dividend.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
Download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='posweb-share-button']")
Download.click()

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. It looks a lot better in Python.
After "Dividend.click" works, it will not click the next button.

Comment: I don’t have a Fidelity account so I can’t really help in this case. Maybe update the OP with these details and someone else can chime in who does. Your original selector looks fine to me, so not sure why you are having issues

Comment: My guess is that button is hidden in some iFrame or behind something that you need to access first, but its hard for me to say without having access to the webpage

Comment: Thanks for the replies. If the button is hidden in some iFrame, is there a code snippet I could use?
When I am on the Dividend page, if you manually click the button, a little tile appears with Print and Download icons. I am trying to get this to appear, so that I can then click the Download icon. Maybe that is the issue.